# Reactivate AFP von Mac High Sierra OS X Server (10.13)

Tags: high-sierra, osx-server, file-sharing, afp, serveradmin

I am having trouble with my High Sierra OS X Server's file sharing volumes. Sometimes the connection is very slow. Other times I can't connect. Then I sometimes have multiple mounted volumes of the same share, but I can't write to any of them.

I don't have any hard drives converted to APFS, so my question was, is there a way to activate AFP from Terminal?

`sudo serveradmin fullstatus afp` shows that there is something still there and I can start the afp demon without any error message with `serveradmin start afp`.

My only question is where do I configure the settings?

Thanks for any suggestions. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item "File Sharing" is entirely removed from Server 5.4. You can still configure the settings in System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing though.

If you you want to manage file sharing from the command line use:

```
sudo serveradmin ...
```

to enable or stop AFP and

```
sudo sharing ...
```

to manage shares.

Example:

Enter `sudo sharing -a /Volumes/Share/Users -A Users` to share the folder /Volumes/Share/Users via AFP and the share name *Users*.

Check `man sharing` for further options and flags.

---

**Shares on APFS volumes can't be shared via AFP!**

Comment: how would I allow users (not groups) to then access the share? and do I set the permissions on the folder? Thanks!

Comment: @Joseph Access permissions directly depend on the folder permissions/ACLs of the shared folder! This is done via chmod/chown or in the GUI: System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing.

Comment: oh - I can still edit those in SysPref. for my AFP shares too despite HSierra? - great. Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph Yes, as written in the 2nd sentence of my answer, System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing GUI ~ `serveradmin` (regarding file sharing) + `sharing` + `chmod`/`chown`.